# Spring framework sqlupdate with nvarchar

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

We are trying to update unicode characters in SQL Server using spring `sqlupdate` with prepared statement. I read that you can set the default `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` but we don't want to do that. I also see you can set the `pstmt.setNString`.

But we are using the `sqlupdate` from spring where we override the update method like this:

We declare the statement like this:

```
setSql("update users set fullname=?");
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));
```

Then run the update like this:

```
public int replace(User user) {
Object[] params = new Object[] { user.getFullName() }
  validateParameters(params);
  return update(params);
}
```

We tried to change the declare to:

```
declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.NVARCHAR));
```

and got an error about not able to convert to ERROR.

Any ideas how to get the unicode to insert using spring update statements?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the full error verbatim.

Comment: And post the whole code, it's very hard to work against such piecemeal of a code